# How can I pass docker environment variables to an npm script?

Tags: node.js, docker, npm, dockerfile, npm-scripts

As the title says...As a noobie I've given this a good attempt but can't seem to figure it out.

I have a dockerfile

```
FROM node:12
WORKDIR /app
COPY . /app
RUN npm config set registry https://registry.npmjs.org/
RUN npm install
EXPOSE 8080
ENTRYPOINT ["npm", "start",]
CMD [ "--", "-e=$ENVIRONMENT", "-t=$TESTS" ]
```

and a script in my package.json like so:

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "node main.js"
  }
```

Main.js is expecting two arguments. e & t.
I am struggling to pass these in to the container to then give to the script to run main.js (note there is a reason why im running it through a script ive just made this example simple)

To run my npm script I can do this:

```
npm start -- -e=abc -t=xyz
```

So I have tried this but no joy:

```
docker run -e ENVIRONMENT=abc -e TESTS=xyz myimage
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you use the JSON form of `CMD` (or `ENTRYPOINT` or `RUN`), there is no interpolation at all; your script should literally see the string `-e=$ENVIRONMENT` as the argument.  Instead you need to use the shell form, which will wrap this in a shell that expands environment variables.  You can't do this with this particular split of `ENTRYPOINT` and `CMD`, but at the same time, it's not really necessary; just put the whole thing in `CMD`.

```sh
# No ENTRYPOINT
# No quoting; Docker wraps this in `sh -c ...`
CMD npm start -- -e="$ENVIRONMENT" -t="$TESTS"
```

You can also handle these directly in your application.  The `yargs` library for example has a [`.env()`](http://yargs.js.org/docs/#api-reference-envprefix) function that allows environment variables to be used directly as options.  You could also make `process.env.TESTS` be the default value for the option if it's not provided directly.  This approach gets around the trouble of constructing (and possibly extending) a valid command line with the combination of arguments you need.

Comment: Thank you very much! I am using the `yargs` library to define my arguments and have set a default for ENVIRONMENT, but the TESTS argument is required. Thanks Again!